# erlang sockets and gen_server - no data received on server side

Tags: sockets, erlang, erlang-supervisor, gen-server

**In a nutshell:**
I am trying to make a socket server to which clients connect and send/receive messages (based on the sockserv code in Learn you some erlang tutorial http://learnyousomeerlang.com/buckets-of-sockets)
Server side components:
supervisor - unique, started at the very beginning, spawns processes with gen_server behaviour 
gen_server behaviour processes - each one deals with a connection.

Client side:
client which connects to the socket and sends a few bytes of data and then disconnects.

**Code details**
My code is pretty much the same as in the presented tutorial. The supervisor is identical. The gen_server component is simplified so that it has only one handle_info case which is supposed to catch everything and just print it.

**Problem**
The connection succeeds, but when the client sends data, the server behaves as though no data is received (I am expecting that handle_info is called when that happens).

handle_info does get called but only when the client disconnects and this event is reported with a message.

**My attempts**
I have played around with different clients written in Erlang or Java, I have tried setting the active/passive state of the socket. The author of the tutorial sets {active, once} after sending a message. I ended up just setting {active, true} after the AcceptSocket is created as such: (the gen_server proc is initialized with a state which contains the original ListenSocket created by the supervisor)

```
handle_cast(accept, S = #state{socket=ListenSocket}) ->

     {ok, AcceptSocket} = gen_tcp:accept(ListenSocket),
     io:format("accepted connection ~n", []),

      sockserv_sup:start_socket(), % a new acceptor is born, praise the lord
      inet:setopts(AcceptSocket, [{active, true}]),
      send(AcceptSocket, "Yellow", []),
      {noreply, S#state{socket=AcceptSocket, next=name}}.

send(Socket, Str, Args) ->
    ok = gen_tcp:send(Socket, io_lib:format(Str++"~n", Args)),
    ok.

   handle_info(E, S) ->
       io:format("mothereffing unexpected: ~p~n", [E]),
       {noreply, S}.
```

It has aboslutely no effect. handle_info only gets called when the connection is lost because the client disconnects. whenever the client sends data nothing happens.

What could be the problem? I have spend quite some time on this, I really have no idea.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To conclude, watch out for the options. I was indeed not paying attention to the implications of the set of options. I tried with a more narrowed down situation and worked it out. My problem was the {packet, line} option which implies that \n is considered a message delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the other options in http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/inet.html#setopts-2

inet:setopts(AcceptSocket, [{active, true}])

for example:

{packet, line} to read in a line at a time

and

binary to read in data as a binary.

I also was working through a similar exercise based on that tutorial recently and my options used were:

inet:setopts(LSocket, [{active,true}, {packet, line}, binary, {reuseaddr, true}]),

Comment: I have tried those options. They have no effect. I have tried a simple interaction between a server socket and a client socket and it works. But somehow, in this context, where the socket is handled by a gen_server, and it should trigger its handle_info function, it does not work.